# LetsEncrypt Certbot- Error Validating SSL Certificate

Tags: ssl, networking, https, ssl-certificate, certbot

I'm trying to create an ssl certificate but I'm gettting  anerror:

Like in my dns provider I put the txt  _acme-challenge with the value etc, but When I try to validate I get the following error:

System: Ubunto

```
Create a file containing just this data:

yN9R6mDDKhezbhE9VWtfJ2E_CcSmuIVfa7PXsmILyz4.WaEiIX5VhENQQPHPYYaoeag_nSPv7aB4EMiaKWyS7wc

And make it available on your web server at this URL:

http://jamelaumn.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/yN9R6mDDKhezbhE9VWtfJ2E_CcSmuIVfa7PXsmILyz4

- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
Press Enter to Continue

Certbot failed to authenticate some domains (authenticator: manual). The Certificate Authority reported these problems:
  Domain: jamelaumn.com
  Type:   connection
  Detail: 111.111.111.111: Fetching http://jamelaumn.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/yN9R6mDDKhezbhE9VWtfJ2E_CcSmuIVfa7PXsmILyz4: Connection refused

Hint: The Certificate Authority failed to verify the manually created challenge files. Ensure that you created these in the correct location.

Some challenges have failed.
Ask for help or search for solutions at https://community.letsencrypt.org. See the logfile /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log or re-run Certbot with -v for more details.
root@jamelaumn:~#
```

[image]
[image]